# Want to search using comman separated text in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am fetching data through ajax and showing on text box  but it does not show suggestion after I insert comma and start searching another text. 
Here is my test box.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEmployee" Text="Employee Search" runat="server"></asp:Label>  
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployee" runat="server" Width="200" placeholder="Employee Name"></asp:TextBox>
```

this is my ajax function.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#txtEmployee").autocomplete({
             source: function (request, response) {
                 var param = { EmpName: $('#txtEmployee').val() };
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "ChangeRequestForm.aspx/getEmployees",
                     data: JSON.stringify(param),
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                     success: function (data) {
                         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                         response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                             return {
                                 value: item.EmpName + " (" + item.Address + ")"
                             }
                         }))
                     },
                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                         alert(err.Message)
                         // console.log("Ajax Error!");    
                     }
                 });
             },
             minLength: 1    
         });
     });
</script>
```

this is my code behind function.

```
           [WebMethod]
    public static List<MonitoringDataFormBE> getEmployees(string EmpName)
    {
        List<MonitoringDataFormBE> empObj = new List<MonitoringDataFormBE>();
        //string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ToString();
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConStringforPhase))
            {
                using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand())
                {
                    com.CommandText = string.Format("select school_code from change_log where school_code like '{0}%'", EmpName);
                    com.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    OracleDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    MonitoringDataFormBE emp = null;
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        emp = new MonitoringDataFormBE();
                        emp.SCHOOL_CODE = Convert.ToString(sdr["SCHOOL_CODE"]);
                        empObj.Add(emp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return empObj;
    }
```

currently giving me suggestion only for one word not after comma in text box while i try to enter any thing in text box after comma.

Comment: Hello, you use asp.net control in Ajax call. Then add text box attributes Clientmode="static"

Comment: can u please tell me how i can do this

Comment: ok i have achieved my desired result. thank u so much for yr help

Comment: you use .net control in ajax call. add <asp:textbox id='abc' runat='server' clientmode='static' >    or not use clientmode='static'  or  $("#<%= txtschoolCode.ClientID %>").val()

Answer (score 0):

I have replace the script by this and error in resolved.

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#txtschoolCode").autocomplete({
             source: function (request, response) {
                 var param = { EmpName: $("#<%= txtschoolCode.ClientID %>").val() };
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "ChangeRequestForm.aspx/getEmployees",
                     data: JSON.stringify(param),
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                     success: function (data) {
                         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                         response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                             return {
                                 value: item.SCHOOL_CODE + " (" + item.Address + ")"
                             }
                         }))
                     },
                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                         alert(err.Message)
                         // console.log("Ajax Error!");    
                     }
                 });
             },
             minLength: 1 //This is the Char length of inputTextBox    
         });
     });
</script>
```